# Reload Express Server after File Upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

This is my very basic express server

```
const express = require("express")
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload")
const cors = require("cors")
const morgan = require("morgan")
const fs = require('fs')

const app = express()

app.use(fileUpload({
  createParentPath: true
}))

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(morgan("dev"));

var result;

const XMLFileExists = fs.existsSync("uploads/uploadedXMLFile.xml") ? true : false;
const uploadFile = () => {

  app.post("/fileUpload", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      if(!req.files){
        res.send({
          status: false,
          message: "No files"
        })
      } else {
        const {XMLFile} = req.files
        XMLFile.mv("./uploads/" + "uploadedXMLFile.xml")
        res.send({
          status: true,
          message: "File is uploaded"
        }) 
      }
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(500).send(e);
    }
  })
}

const runReader = () => {
  // uploadFile()
  if(XMLFileExists){
    result = fs.readFileSync("uploads/uploadedXMLFile.xml", "utf-8");
    app.get('/fileReader', (req, res) => res.send(result));
  }
}

uploadFile()
runReader()

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`))
```

As you can see, it has two functions. One that handles the upload of the file called `uploadFile()` and another one that reads the file called `runReader()`.

**The Process**

I upload a file => It saves it to `upload/` in the directory => the file gets read and becomes available at `localhost:5000/fileReader` for the frontend to access.

**The problem is** that whenever I upload a `file1` and then a new `file2`, the server does not reload even with nodemon, and what is available at `localhost` is the file1.

**It gets fixed** when I manually do a `Ctrl + S` for the nodemon to restart the server.
I want to restart the server on file upload so the latest file is available at the `localhost`

Comment: Is there something I can put in my code to make the server programmatically restart?

Comment: You can simply run `runReader` after the upload

Comment: @ThomasSablik for some reason that does not work. I'm very new to backend so I have no idea why it is happening

Comment: You are registering a function to a route. I thought you can overwrite the function. You can update `result` after the upload.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Can you show me how that can be done?

Comment: `result = fs.readFileSync("uploads/uploadedXMLFile.xml", "utf-8");`

Answer (score 0):

This was actually my bad, I had no idea how middleware worked.
I watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY6icfhap2o&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified) video and it totally solved my problem.

This solution down below works for me. I forgot to add this in the actual answer.

```
const express = require("express")
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload")
const cors = require("cors")
const morgan = require("morgan")
const fs = require('fs')

const app = express()


const XMLFileExists = fs.existsSync("uploads/uploadedXMLFile.xml") ? true : false;

app.use(fileUpload({
  createParentPath: true
}))

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(morgan("dev"))


app.post("/fileUpload", (req, res) => {
  try {
    if(!req.files){
      res.send({
        status: false,
        message: "No files"
      })
    } else {
      const {XMLFile} = req.files
      
      XMLFile.mv("./uploads/" + "uploadedXMLFile.xml")
      res.send({
        status: true,
        message: "File is uploaded"
      })
    }
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(e);
  }
})


function readXMLFile (req, res, next) {

  if(XMLFileExists){
     res.result = fs.readFileSync("uploads/uploadedXMLFile.xml", "utf-8");
    console.log('text online')
  }
  next()
}

app.get('/fileReader', readXMLFile, (req, res) => res.send(res.result));

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`))
```

I was thinking that the functions in middleware worked like normal functions. That is not true. Every function is a middleware.
When you read about middleware, there are three things in this concept => `req`, `res` and `next`

Every middleware gets a `req` (request) and sends a `res` (response). Then they can call `next()` if they want the data to go to the next function and modify the data. It starts from the top and gets to the bottom going through every middleware where we send a response back. The order of the middleware is very important.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

All code outside middlewares is executed once on start of server.

So move `const XMLFileExists = fs.existsSync("uploads/uploadedXMLFile.xml") ? true : false;`

Into readXMLFile function then you won't need to restart the server.